# jQuery - get a value from dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Please see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/28/

1. Add Input - adds new row with new input
2. Get Value - is getting value of last added input

I am creating some extra rows (invoice element), but when I want to use get the value in dynamically created input, but the input value is always `undefined`. Why?

**Why jQuery can not find value of dynamically created input?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is enough for what you want:

```
$('#GetValue').click(function() {
    var i = $('table tbody tr').length-1; // subtract 1 for correct indexing
    alert($('#ItemPrice-' + i).val());
    // OR
    alert( $('[id^=ItemPrice]:last').val() );
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/31/)***

#### According to comment with jsfiddle

The problem is:

```
tableRow += '<td><input type="text" name="ItemPrice[]" id="ItemPrice-' + i + ' " 
                                                                              ^--- an space
placeholder="Item Price"></td>';

tableRow += '<td><input type="text" name="NumberOfItems[]" id="NumberOfItems-' + i + ' " 
                                                                                      ^-- an space
placeholder="Number Of Items"></td>';
```

***[Here is update and working code](http://jsfiddle.net/JF38y/13/)***

Comment: Great! That fixed the issue. However, I did not illustrated the issue properly; see here: http://jsfiddle.net/JF38y/11/ When you create new row the inline calc does not work. `$("#ItemPrice-" + RowIndex)` is always undefined. The problem is that jQuery cannot find the dynamically created input. Any idea?

Comment: Good eye! Is this because jQuery is looking for an ID as a string, meaning getting the space into count as well? Firebug actually displays the space as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#GetValue').click(function() {

    var i = $('table tbody tr').length; // this line is the issue

    alert($('#ItemPrice-' + i).val());

});​
```

I've copied the function in your code which is giving you the issue. The line I've highlighted should be this:

```
var i = $('table tbody tr').length-1;
```

This is because arrays in Javascript are 0-indexed, meaning they start counting upwards from zero. This means that if you want to get the last element of the array, you need to find the length of the array and subtract one, as I've demonstrated.

This line:

```
alert($('#ItemPrice-' + i).val());
```

actually returns an array, which starts counting at 0. That's why getting the element at position `array.length` returns undefined.

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/29/) as proof.